# Summing values in read_csv Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table in csv using pandas:

```
Name     A   B   C
aa       0   5   7
aa       1   2   3
aa       1   5   6
aa       0   8   9
aa       1   8   9
aa       1   8   9
ab       0   8   9
ab       1   8   9
ab       1   8   9
ab       1   8   9
ac       0   8   9
ac       0   8   9
```

What i need to do is to summ all the C for equal Name if A=1, so the output should be like Name: {first of B: sum(C for this A)}. 
I need a separate sum for each patch of 1 in A. 
For example, first 1 for aa appears in the second line, so we take B for this (here its 2), then take C. We go to the next line, A=1 again, then we sum its C with the previous C (from the 2nd line). The 4th A=0, so we don't take this string and go ahead. The 5th A=1 again, so we do the first step again: keep B=8 and sum all the next C that have A=1
For example,

```
aa: {2:3+6, 8:9+9} //here 2 is B when A=1 for the first time
ab: {8: 9+9+9}
ac: {*nothing, because no 1*}
```

I know it's easy, but i'm new in python and got stuck with iterating through columns

Comment: To prove that you have tried, could you show where exactly you get stuck with a simple code example?

Comment: also, to understand, why is it 2:3+6 and not 2:3 and 5:6, is it just because there is no A=0 in between?

Comment: firstly i started with 
 **for i in table('Name'):
                                 for j in table('A):
                                       for k in table('B'):
                                          for z in table('C'):
                                               while j==1:
                                                    sum('C')** `code`
but then i got it's delirium, and aterted tinkering with pivot table, but still didn't sucseed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need helper column `count` and then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.aggregate.html) first value by [`first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) and [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html). Then you need subset by mask `df.A == 1` and last you can [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) columns `A` and `count`:

```
df['count'] = (df['A'].diff(1) != 0).astype('int').cumsum()
print df
   Name  A  B  C  count
0    aa  0  5  7      1
1    aa  1  2  3      2
2    aa  1  5  6      2
3    aa  0  8  9      3
4    aa  1  8  9      4
5    aa  1  8  9      4
6    ab  0  8  9      5
7    ab  1  8  9      6
8    ab  1  8  9      6
9    ab  1  8  9      6
10   ac  0  8  9      7
11   ac  0  8  9      7
```

```
df = df.groupby(['Name','A', 'count']).agg({'B' : 'first', 'C' : 'sum'}).reset_index()
print df
  Name  A  count   C  B
0   aa  0      1   7  5
1   aa  0      3   9  8
2   aa  1      2   9  2
3   aa  1      4  18  8
4   ab  0      5   9  8
5   ab  1      6  27  8
6   ac  0      7  18  8

df = df[df.A == 1]
print df
  Name  A  count   C  B
2   aa  1      2   9  2
3   aa  1      4  18  8
5   ab  1      6  27  8

df = df.drop(['A','count'], axis=1)
print df
  Name   C  B
2   aa   9  2
3   aa  18  8
5   ab  27  8
```

How I get column `count`:

```
print df['A'].diff(1) 
0    NaN
1      1
2      0
3     -1
4      1
5      0
6     -1
7      1
8      0
9      0
10    -1
11     0
Name: A, dtype: float64

print df['A'].diff(1) != 0
0      True
1      True
2     False
3      True
4      True
5     False
6      True
7      True
8     False
9     False
10     True
11    False
Name: A, dtype: bool
```

```
print (df['A'].diff(1) != 0).astype('int')
0     1
1     1
2     0
3     1
4     1
5     0
6     1
7     1
8     0
9     0
10    1
11    0
Name: A, dtype: int32

print (df['A'].diff(1) != 0).astype('int').cumsum()
0     1
1     2
2     2
3     3
4     4
5     4
6     5
7     6
8     6
9     6
10    7
11    7
Name: A, dtype: int32
```