# finding streaks in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe as follows:

```
time    winner  loser   stat
1       A       B       0
2       C       B       0
3       D       B       1
4       E       B       0
5       F       A       0
6       G       A       0
7       H       A       0
8       I       A       1
```

each row is a match result. the first column is the time of the match, second and third column contain winner/loser and the fourth column is one stat from the match.

I want to detect streaks of zeros for this stat per loser.

The expected result should look like this:

```
time    winner  loser   stat    streak
1       A       B       0       1
2       C       B       0       2
3       D       B       1       0
4       E       B       0       1
5       F       A       0       1
6       G       A       0       2
7       H       A       0       3
8       I       A       1       0
```

In pseudocode the algorithm should work like this:

- `.groupby` `loser` column.
- then iterate over each row of each `loser` group
- in each row, look at the `stat` column: if it contains `0`, then increment the `streak` value from the previous row by `0`. if it is not `0`, then start a new `streak`, that is, put `0` into the `streak` column.

So the `.groupby` is clear. But then I would need some sort of `.apply` where I can look at the previous row? this is where I am stuck.

Comment: Not exactly an answer, but it think the solution might be found by combining [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17266129/python-pandas-conditional-sums) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35314936/summing-values-in-read-csv-python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not as elegant as jezrael's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35428677/5276797), but for me easier to understand...

First, define a function that works with a single loser:

```
def f(df):
    df['streak2'] = (df['stat'] == 0).cumsum()
    df['cumsum'] = np.nan
    df.loc[df['stat'] == 1, 'cumsum'] = df['streak2']
    df['cumsum'] = df['cumsum'].fillna(method='ffill')
    df['cumsum'] = df['cumsum'].fillna(0)
    df['streak'] = df['streak2'] - df['cumsum']
    df.drop(['streak2', 'cumsum'], axis=1, inplace=True)
    return df
```

The streak is essentially a `cumsum`, but we need to reset it each time `stat` is 1. We therefore subtract the value of the `cumsum` where `stat` is 1, carried forward until the next 1.

Then `groupby` and `apply` by loser:

```
df.groupby('loser').apply(f)
```

The result is as expected.

Comment: i like this solution most, because it's really transparent. moreover, jezrael's answer only works if the stat column has 0 or 1 values.. in fact, my real data also contains other values (e.g. 3, 4, 5) in the stat column. sorry, that's of course my bad, for not pointing this out in my example. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 14):

You can [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) custom function `f`, then [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html), [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
def f(x):
    x['streak'] = x.groupby( (x['stat'] != 0).cumsum()).cumcount() + 
                  ( (x['stat'] != 0).cumsum() == 0).astype(int) 
    return x

df = df.groupby('loser', sort=False).apply(f)
print df
   time winner loser  stat  streak
0     1      A     B     0       1
1     2      C     B     0       2
2     3      D     B     1       0
3     4      E     B     0       1
4     5      F     A     0       1
5     6      G     A     0       2
6     7      H     A     0       3
7     8      I     A     1       0
```

For better undestanding:

```
def f(x):
    x['c'] = (x['stat'] != 0).cumsum()
    x['a'] = (x['c'] == 0).astype(int)
    x['b'] = x.groupby( 'c' ).cumcount()

    x['streak'] = x.groupby( 'c' ).cumcount() + x['a']

    return x
df = df.groupby('loser', sort=False).apply(f)
print df
   time winner loser  stat  c  a  b  streak
0     1      A     B     0  0  1  0       1
1     2      C     B     0  0  1  1       2
2     3      D     B     1  1  0  0       0
3     4      E     B     0  1  0  1       1
4     5      F     A     0  0  1  0       1
5     6      G     A     0  0  1  1       2
6     7      H     A     0  0  1  2       3
7     8      I     A     1  1  0  0       0
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`iterrows`](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi-rr3K__vKAhVH8XIKHY3CAagQFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpandas.pydata.org%2Fpandas-docs%2Fstable%2Fgenerated%2Fpandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html&usg=AFQjCNFoarIWRLVigWAUuKSEEyd7nsM3sg&bvm=bv.114195076,d.bGQ) to access previous row:

```
df['streak'] = 0

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if i != 0:
        if row['stat'] == 0:
            if row['loser'] == df.ix[i-1, 'loser']:
                df.ix[i, 'streak'] = df.ix[i-1, 'streak'] + 1        
            else:
                df.ix[i, 'streak'] = 1
    else:
        if row['stat'] == 0:
            df.ix[i, 'streak'] = 1
```

Which gives:

```
In [210]: df
Out[210]:
   time winner loser  stat  streak
0     1      A     B     0       1
1     2      C     B     0       2
2     3      D     B     1       0
3     4      E     B     0       1
4     5      F     A     0       1
5     6      G     A     0       2
6     7      H     A     0       3
7     8      I     A     1       0
```