# Cumsum Reset based on a condition in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, cumsum

My question is very similar to [Cumsum within group and reset on condition in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47741626/cumsum-within-group-and-reset-on-condition-in-pandas) and [Pandas: cumsum per category based on additional condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44552826/pandas-cumsum-per-category-based-on-additional-condition) but they don't quite get me there due to my conditional requirements. I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
  TransactionId     Delta
          14          2
          14          3
          14          1
          14          2
          15          4
          15          2
          15          3
```

I want to create another column "Cumulative" that calculates the cumsum of Delta for each TransactionId. So the result would look like this:

```
  TransactionId     Delta    Cumulative
          14          2          2
          14          3          5
          14          1          6
          14          2          8
          15          4          4
          15          2          6
          15          3          9
```

I have the condition for checking TransactionId equality setup:

```
c1 = df.TransactionId.eq(df.TransactionId.shift())
```

But I can't figure out how to add the Delta value to the previous Cumulative row.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [`groupby.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html):

```
df['Cumulative'] = df.groupby('TransactionId')['Delta'].cumsum()

print (df)

  TransactionId  Delta  Cumulative
0       14         2       2
1       14         3       5
2       14         1       6
3       14         2       8
4       15         4       4 
5       15         2       6 
6       15         3       9
```

Comment: This is the most clear explanation of this problem that I have seen.

Comment: What if `TransactionId` would be a bool and you want to restart count if bool = True ?