# Python pandas column increment

Tags: python, pandas, increment

I can't make a function for a column (`df['contribution']`) where when it's greater than 0 (>0), you increment by 1 to calculate the number of times it's greater than 0. Thank you for your help

Comment: `df['contribution'].gt(0).cumsum()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cumsum Reset based on a condition in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53079313/cumsum-reset-based-on-a-condition-in-pandas)

Comment: thanks for your help :)