# Group streaks of ones (with a twist)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have read related questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35427298/finding-streaks-in-pandas-dataframe) and [this blog post](https://joshdevlin.com/blog/calculate-streaks-in-pandas/).

Unfortunately I am unable to modify the solutions to my needs.

Consider a Series with a DatetimeIndex which may look like this:

[image]

Code to instantiate an example:

```
s = pd.Series([0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0], index=pd.date_range(start=0, freq='1d', periods=12, name='A')
```

Ultimately, I want to get the result

```
  (t4 - t1)
+ (t8 - t5)
+ (t10 - t8)
```

This means **I need to identify streaks of `1` padded with `0` on each side**. I can do everything after that myself, i.e. grouping by streak (possibly with `cumcount`) and diffing the first and last timestamp in each group.

There are some special cases when the Series starts/ends with a `1`.In this case I want to treat it as if it was preceded/followed by a `0` at the same timestamp, e.g.

[image]

---

Attempt so far:

I'm going to concat some sub-solutions for easier visualization.

1. Pad the series with a zero on each end, to avoid special cases.

   ```
   s = pd.Series([0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0], index=pd.date_range(start=0, freq='1d', periods=12, name='A')
   s = pd.concat([pd.Series([0], index=s.index[:1]), s, pd.Series([0], index=s.index[-1:])])
   ```
2. Get the last `0` before and the first `0` after a streak of ones.

   ```
    >>> tmp = pd.concat([s, s.diff(-1).eq(-1).astype(int).rename('starter'), s.diff(1).eq(-1).astype(int).rename('ender')], axis=1)
    >>> tmp 
                A  starter  ender
    1970-01-01  0        0      0
    1970-01-02  0        1      0
    1970-01-03  1        0      0
    1970-01-04  1        0      0
    1970-01-05  0        0      1
    1970-01-06  0        1      0
    1970-01-07  1        0      0
    1970-01-08  1        0      0
    1970-01-09  0        1      1
    1970-01-10  1        0      0
    1970-01-11  0        0      1
    1970-01-12  0        0      0
   ```
3. Fill single zero gaps in the `'A'` column with `1` because they don't change the desired result. (This step might not be necessary but helps the visualization.)

   ```
    >>> tmp.loc[(both := tmp['starter'].eq(1) & tmp['ender'].eq(1)), 'A'] = 1
    >>> tmp
                A  starter  ender
    1970-01-01  0        0      0
    1970-01-02  0        1      0
    1970-01-03  1        0      0
    1970-01-04  1        0      0
    1970-01-05  0        0      1
    1970-01-06  0        1      0
    1970-01-07  1        0      0
    1970-01-08  1        0      0
    1970-01-09  1        1      1
    1970-01-10  1        0      0
    1970-01-11  0        0      1
    1970-01-12  0        0      0
   ```
4. Adjust the `'starter'` and `'ender'` columns.

   ```
    >>> tmp.loc[both, ['starter', 'ender']] = 0
    >>> tmp 
                A  starter  ender
    1970-01-01  0        0      0
    1970-01-02  0        1      0
    1970-01-03  1        0      0
    1970-01-04  1        0      0
    1970-01-05  0        0      1
    1970-01-06  0        1      0
    1970-01-07  1        0      0
    1970-01-08  1        0      0
    1970-01-09  1        0      0
    1970-01-10  1        0      0
    1970-01-11  0        0      1
    1970-01-12  0        0      0
   ```

And this is where I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was almost done in the attempt from the question, here's the completion:

```
result = (s.index[s.diff(1).eq(-1)] - s.index[s.diff(-1).eq(-1)]).sum()
```

Assumes `s` starts and ends with a zero. Otherwise apply padding with zeros first.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution to your problem:

```py
>>> s = pd.Series([0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0], index=pd.date_range(start=0, freq='1d', periods=6))

1970-01-01    0
1970-01-02    1
1970-01-03    1
1970-01-04    0
1970-01-05    1
1970-01-06    0
```

```py
>>> s2 = s.diff(1)

1970-01-01    NaN
1970-01-02    1.0
1970-01-03    0.0
1970-01-04   -1.0
1970-01-05    1.0
1970-01-06   -1.0
```

```py
>>> s3 = s2.loc[s == 0].reset_index(name="d0")

    index       d0
0   1970-01-01  NaN
1   1970-01-04  -1.0
2   1970-01-06  -1.0
```

```py
>>> s4 = s3["index"].diff(1).loc[s3["d0"] == -1]

1   3 days
2   2 days

>>> s4.sum().days
5
```

**Putting it all together,**

```py
s.diff(1) \
    .loc[s == 0] \
    .reset_index(name="val_diff") \
    .assign(date_diff=lambda x: x["index"].diff(1)) \
    .loc[lambda x: x.val_diff == -1] \
    .date_diff.sum()
```

---

For the special cases, add extra rows to the top and bottom of the dataframe if they start or end with value = 1. Something like:

```py
if s.iloc[0] == 1:
    s = pd.concat([
            pd.Series([0], index=s.index[:1]),
            s
    ])
```